# Trying to get php to run on cron

Tags: php, cron

This is driving me a little insane, and I've gone through a hundered different things without touching on the solution; so I may miss out on some details on what I've done so far.

I'm trying to get a Cron job to run on my linux server ive got running in a datacentre. All I'm trying to get to run is a simple php script in the format:

```
* * * * * php -q /path/to/script/file.php
```

The php part runs fine if I type it in manually, but nothing happens when the cron runs; it also appears to run in the logs just fine, with no errors.

If i go back and edit with crontab -e, and put in the line

```
* * * * * echo "test" > /tmp/test.txt
```

That seems to work ok, it creates the text file.

Has anyone had any problems running a php script in this format?

(Btw I'm just testing with the run every minute, it doesnt work at any time.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I love that everyone gave the same answer in about 1 minute :)

Comment: Hahaha yea mate, thanks everyone unfortunately I can only give one of them the correct answer award and dont have rep to award anyone else. You all have a moral victory however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try invoking php with it's full path, for example /usr/bin/php

the cron will not have the same environment variables as your user profile have, so it might not find the executable.

Comment: was that supposed to say "not" instead of "now"?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put full path to php binary (/usr/bin/php or similar)

I also don't have '-q' flag in my distribution. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Might just be some path craziness: I'd run `which php` and then copy the full path into cron. On one of my boxes it is `/usr/bin/php` and so you'd have:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/script/file.php
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your PHP binary is not in your PATH. Try using the full path:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php -q /path/to/script/file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you may need to provide the full path to your php binary

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/script/file.php
```